# Scraping a json request `ak` parameter value

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, hash, m3u8

I'm currently trying to scrape embedded m3u8 url paths for self-study.

So far, I managed to pin down the request produces a json response with the m3u8 information.

For example, the https://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/videonews/ann?a=20190527-00000051-ann-soci page would make the following request:

`https://feapi-yvpub.yahooapis.jp/v1/content/1579522?appid=dj0zaiZpPVZMTVFJR0FwZWpiMyZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9YjU-&output=json&space_id=2078710307&domain=headlines.yahoo.co.jp&ak=e25b66ca8b37b7a383feecf4e084fe95&device_type=1100&thumb_width=1204&thumb_height=676&thumb_priority=l&thumb_bd=0`

In order to make a successful request, the `contentid` (1579522), `appid`, `space_id`, `device_type`, and `ak` parameters are required. I managed to scrape the id and device_type values but have no idea where to get the `ak` value, which I guess stands for access key. Any idea on how to get this value?

Side note: I accessed the page through different browsers and they all produced the same `ak` parameter value in the request, so I'm guessing the value is not uniquely linked to each session, but I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mystery argument `ak` is created by first combining `space_id` and `domain` into a single string such as `"2078710307_headlines.yahoo.co.jp"`. Then it is run through an obfuscator which is located in `player.script.js`.

The obfuscator looks a bit complicated and seems to be made hard to understand on purpose. Below are debugger screenshots from the obfuscator main function, and a subroutine that it calls.

[image]

[image]

While a bit daunting, it doesn't seem impossible to convert this to a Python program so that you could then get `ak` by obfuscating any `space_id` and `domain` you needed in youtube-dl. Good luck.

Comment: A search on some of the obfuscation code lead me to understand that it's a md5 hash generator function. Thank you for your help.